# Turn on/off Jquery Validation for one input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the same form to add and edit values.  During addition of an item, I want it to force a name check against the server, which it does.  However, during edit mode I want it to not validate, since the name may not change.  I tried to set the ignore property in the validator to the "ignore" class, based on the documentation, link below.  I use that same class name in the name input, but that does not work.  It kept validating against the server.  Any thoughts?

URL to the code I am using, primarily the validate function. http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Based on the the documentation for the ignore property, it states:

*Elements to ignore when validating, simply filtering them out. jQuery’s not-method is used, therefore everything that is accepted by not() can be passed as this option. Inputs of type submit and reset are always ignored, so are disabled elements.*

I looked in the code and could only see it impacting clean up of errors during the call to `validator.resetForm()`.  This part of the code works correctly.

Comment: Please show your code including the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: The problem description seems genuine. Why it was marked as off-topic?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

- You cannot toggle the jQuery Validate plugin on/off for the form or for individual field elements.  There is no method or workaround for this.
- The `ignore` option is set within the `.validate()` call, which is a "one-time" initialization of the plugin, so you cannot change or toggle options dynamically.  Any subsequent calls to `.validate()` are always ignored.

After initializing the plugin with `.validate()`, your only solution would be to use the `.rules()` method to dynamically `'add'` and `'remove'` rules for individual field elements.  Don't be fooled by the `'add'` terminology... this method also allows you to overwrite existing rules, so you don't necessarily have to `'remove'` them first.

To dynamically set the field as `required`:

```
$('#myfield').rules('add', {
    required: true   // set a new rule
});
```

To dynamically set the field as **not** `required`:

```
$('#myfield').rules('add', {
    required: false   // overwrite an existing rule
});
```

OR

```
$('#myfield').rules('remove', 'required');  // removes only specified rule(s)
```

OR

```
$('#myfield').rules('remove');  // removes all rules for this field
```

**Documentation**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Comment: This is the best answer on the internet! I was looking for this for a long time. Works great.

Comment: I was looking for this solution from around 5 days...Thank you very much

Comment: @Rick, that's just not true.   And if you have a new question, please post a new question, do not ask within comments.

Comment: Thanks, it had been driving me nuts trying to locate this info.