# Asp.Net MVC jQuery validation event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have been trying to ignore validating few HTML elements in MVC-3 application.
In non Microsoft environment (we don't have to write validation rules, comes from Model) I would write below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").each(function () {
        $(this).validate({
            ignore: ".ignore"
        });
    });
});
```

But it is not working for MVC application. Which event should I hack into?

More Info:

The idea is to add `ignore` class to the elements not needing validation. I have added `ignore` class to my html elements separately.

Comment: Why not just remove the validation attributes from your view model properties?

Comment: I suggest you read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016053/turn-on-off-jquery-validation-for-one-input)

Comment: [Simon's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853416/jquery-disable-rule-validation-on-a-single-field) may also help