# How to disable jquery validation on certain input fields

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, jquery-validate

Is there any way to disbale jquery validation on certain input fields inside a form? So that it won't bother me with the 'red text under my input' or whenever I submit my form. I'm searching for a while now but without any succes. I tried using `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons) questions but also without any succes.

Here's my cshtml input code:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="preExposure" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="preExposure" id="preExposureInput" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="preExposure" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016053/turn-on-off-jquery-validation-for-one-input

Answer (score 0):

Although I posted as a comment that it was pretty similar to the linked question, the most important part of that answer is below:

Once you have the jquery validation turned on for the form with the `.validate()` you can still configure the rules for the individual element that you want, and remove all the rules.

`$('#myfield').rules('remove');  // removes all rules for this field`